# Showing $\cot 20^\circ-\sec10^\circ=\sqrt{3}$ by manipulating the left-hand side of the equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

It is quite easy to show the identity
$$\cot20^\circ-\sec10^\circ=\cot30^\circ \quad(= \sqrt{3})$$
manipulating both sides of this last equality; I am looking for a trick allowing to get it by **transforming
the LHS  only**.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Subtract $\sqrt 3$ from $\cot 20^\circ$ to get $\sec 10^\circ$. Then further subtract the $\sec 10^\circ$ and add $\sqrt 3$ to get the right side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
LHS&=\frac{\cos(20^\circ)-2\sin(10^\circ)}{\sin(20^\circ)}\\
\\
&=\frac{2\sin(30^\circ)\cos(20^\circ)-2\sin(10^\circ)}
{\sin(20^\circ)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\sin(30^\circ+20^\circ)+\sin(30^\circ-20^\circ)-2\sin(10^\circ)}{\sin(20^\circ)}\\
\\
&=\frac{\sin(50^\circ)-\sin(10^\circ)}{\sin(20^\circ)}\\
\\
&=\frac{2\cos(30^\circ)\sin(20^\circ)}{\sin(20^\circ)}\\
\\
&=\sqrt{3}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks ; multiplying by 2sin(30∘)  was the trick I looked for !

Comment: Great, you are welcome.